# Derivatives and Primes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

When doing this problem, I got the answer y=21(x+1) but am unable to input due to only accepting numerical values. Am I wrong in my form of working through this problem?

[image]

Comment: What did you get for $f'(x)$?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I was finding an equation rather than just plugging in. The answer was -12.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was -12. I was finding an equation rather than just plugging in

Comment: Please comment this or give a detailed solution.